# How do I use IDbConnection withing my apphost

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I like to know how to access the IDbConnection from within my Global Filters, what I have so far is this.

Now the more I think about it, I don't IDb stuff in my apphost, so how may I retrieve my repository that wraps the ormlite 'stuff' and Cache?

Thank you,
Stephen

**Global.asax**

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{


    var dbConnectionFactory =
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("test"), true, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);

    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbConnectionFactory); 

    RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
        {

            // Do something here with either my repo or ormLite

        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got access to the container you can just do:

```
RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) => {
    using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open()) 
    {
        // Do something here with either my repo or ormLite
    }
});
```

Otherwise you can access it via the `AppHostBase.Resolve<T>` singleton:

```
RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) => {
    using (var db = AppHostBase.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open()) 
    {
        // Do something here with either my repo or ormLite
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually used it both ways, but not with the connection, but my repository. Thanks again @Demis for showing me the ways.